# Push to Heroku failed - error fsevents@0.2.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`

Tags: node.js, heroku, node-gyp, fsevents

I'm trying to push my app to Heroku but I keep getting this error, looks like an issue with **node-gyp** but no idea how to go about fixing it.

```
2854 verbose rebuildBundles fsevents@0.2.0
2855 verbose rebuildBundles [ 'nan' ]
2856 info install fsevents@0.2.0
2857 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
2858 info fsevents@0.2.0 Failed to exec install script
2859 error fsevents@0.2.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
2859 error Exit status 1
2860 error Failed at the fsevents@0.2.0 install script.
2860 error This is most likely a problem with the fsevents package,
2860 error not with npm itself.
2860 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2860 error     node-gyp rebuild
2860 error You can get their info via:
2860 error     npm owner ls fsevents
2860 error There is likely additional logging output above.
2861 error System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
2862 error command "/tmp/build_31f84d3a-9303-49cd-9596-cc7e984d9e18/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_31f84d3a-9303-49cd-9596-cc7e984d9e18/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
2863 error cwd /tmp/build_31f84d3a-9303-49cd-9596-cc7e984d9e18
2864 error node -v v0.10.28
2865 error npm -v 1.4.9
2866 error code ELIFECYCLE
2867 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

Comment: I am having this problem with the `imagemagick-native` module. Any luck on getting yours to work? I also had this issue on my local machine, but fixed it by following the directions here: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/363#issuecomment-33212812

Answer (score 0):

[`fsevents` is a Mac OS X only extension](https://github.com/pipobscure/fsevents#native-access-to-mac-os-x-fsevents) and fails to install on Heroku (Linux). Try making the dependency optional using [`optionalDependencies`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#optionaldependencies) in `package.json`.

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work. I've also set NPM_CONFIG_OPTIONAL to false but it didn't work either. https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config